# grammar rule for prepositions

Tags: prepositions

What is the grammar rule for the preposition after the word free? Why do we say free of impurities but free of charge?

Comment: Welcome to English SE, @teacher! I'm not sure what you're asking here; why "impurities" is plural but "charge" is not, when following "free of"?

Answer (score 2):

The "charge" vs. "impurities" difference you actually seem to be asking about is nothing to do with the preposition as such; it's to do with "charge" being a "mass noun", so not calling for pluralization, and "impurity" being a "count noun", which it's appropriate to pluralize here.

This distinction is the same one as produces the ["less vs. fewer"](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/less-versus-fewer.aspx) dichotomy.

Answer (score 1):

There are other prepositions you could use with "free" as well:

- I am free from two till four this afternoon.
- I would like to be free of this burden.
- A soft drink comes free with purchase.
- You are free to do what you want.
- The offer is free while supplies last.
- Hang on, I'll be free in five minutes.
- I'm free at last!

I could go on ...